# Adding images dynamically to photoswipe

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

Is there a way to add images dynamically to a photoswipe gallery after it is created.

The situation is this.

I'm fetching image urls from the sever and showing them in a gallery.  As the items are downloaded the anchor and img elements are added to the page.  I would like to be able to at that same time append each to the photoswipe gallery.

currently in the element callback (after the image has been loaded and elements appended) I have

```
 $elements.photoSwipe({ enableMouseWheel: false , enableKeyboard: false });
```

This works except it creates each element in it's own gallery.  Is there a way to get a handle to an existing gallery and just append to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(this.photoSwipe == undefined){
   this.photoSwipe = $elements.photoSwipe(photoSwipeOptions);
}else{
    this.photoSwipe.append($elements);  //use jQuery append
}
```

Comment: Photoswipe has no append() method.

Comment: append is a jQuery method not a Photoswipe method.  Note that this.photoSwipe is a jQuery object.  http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Still I have to agree with Adam, if I try your code I get a TypeError: this.photoSwipe.append is not a function, could you please elaborate how you got this to work?

Comment: PhotoSwipe documentation says nothing about append method. You may add items dynamically by altering pswp.gallery items. See this answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/46525547/2190075.

Answer (score 0):

I have committed a pull request for PhotoSwipe

[Pull Request](https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/pull/1460)

If you do have such need to dynamic prepend/append/remove items without change the state of the current item, you can use this version.